# Pandas new column with values from same id, following codition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns I'll provide code to a artificial df for reproduction:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(product([0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2])), columns=['A', 'B','C'])
df['D'] = range(len(df))
```

This results in the following dataframe:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  1
2  0  0  2  2
3  0  1  0  3
4  0  1  1  4
5  0  1  2  5
6  0  2  0  6
7  0  2  1  7
8  0  2  2  8
9  1  0  0  9
```

I want to get a new column `new_C` That takes the C value where B fullfills a condition and spreads it over all matching values in Column A.

The following code does exactly that:

```py
new_df = df[['A','B', 'D']].loc[df['C'] == 0]
new_df.columns = ['A', 'B','new_D']
df = df.merge(new_df, on=['A', 'B'], how= 'outer')
```

However, I a strongly believe there is a better solution to this, where I do not have to introduce a whole new DataFrame and merging it back together.
Preferable a oneliner.

Thanks in advance.

Desired Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  new_D
0  0  0  0  0      0
1  0  0  1  1      0
2  0  0  2  2      0
3  0  1  0  3      3
4  0  1  1  4      3
5  0  1  2  5      3
6  0  2  0  6      6
7  0  2  1  7      6
8  0  2  2  8      6
9  1  0  0  9      9
```

EDIT:
Adding other example:

```
   A  B    C  D
   A  B    C  D
0  0  4  foo  0
1  0  4  bar  1
2  0  4  baz  2
3  0  5  foo  3
4  0  5  bar  4
5  0  5  baz  5
6  0  6  foo  6
7  0  6  bar  7
8  0  6  baz  8
9  1  4  foo  9
```

Should be turned into the following with the condition being:`df['C'] == 'bar'`

```
   A  B    C  D  new_D
0  0  4  foo  0      1
1  0  4  bar  1      1
2  0  4  baz  2      1
3  0  5  foo  3      4
4  0  5  bar  4      4
5  0  5  baz  5      4
6  0  6  foo  6      7
7  0  6  bar  7      7
8  0  6  baz  8      7
9  1  4  foo  9     10
```

Meaning all numbers are arbetrary. Order is also not the same, it just happens to work to take the first number.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of what you want to achieve (I said *what* not *how*). I have a good guess (see my answer), but not 100% sure.

Comment: I had it the way you wrote it before. But because of changes I can't be sure anymore its the first entry, it has to be a condition ( like `df.loc[df['col_name'] == value]`)
The goal is to get a baseline value that I want to subtract values from in the future. Like, I find my name in the dataset and compute the delta. The easiest way I could think of is introducing a column with my name for all the classes i participated in. The usecase is completely different, but I can't talk about it.

Comment: Don't you just put value from column D to new_D if C equals 0? And then values below get the same until there is a new 0 in column C?

Comment: Zero is arbitrarily chosen in this case. In the real case is could be 420, 'foo' or 'bar'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a new baseline every time C equals zero, you can use:

```
df['new_D'] = df['D'].where(df['C'].eq(0)).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

#### old answer

What you want is not fully clear, but it looks like you want to repeat the first item per group of A and B. You can easily achieve this with:

```
df['new_D'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['D'].transform('first')
```

Even simpler, if your data is really composed of consecutive integers:

```
df['D'] = df['D']//3*3
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunaty the value isn't always the first.

Comment: A forwordfill still wont work. Since the item is not always the first one.